# Service not installed, but still listed

Tags: ubuntu, services, uninstall

I have deinstalled `memcached`:

```
» sudo apt-get remove memcached
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ieee-data python-netaddr python-selinux
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  memcached
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
After this operation, 246 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 377925 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing memcached (1.4.25-2ubuntu1.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
```

But the service is still listed:

```
» sudo service --status-all 2> /dev/null | grep memcached
 [ - ]  memcached
```

Why? What can I do to cleanup the list of services?

This is my system:

```
» lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: `sudo apt purge --auto-remove memcached`